# Vaadin Spring Boot cannot find npm packages

Tags: java, spring-boot, npm, vaadin

I have an existing Spring Boot application that I am looking to add a Vaadin frontend to.

I have a simple view class that is as follows:

```
@Route(value = "admin")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private TextField field = new TextField("Message");
    private Button button = new Button("Click Me");

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        button.addClickListener(e -> Notification.show("Message: " + field.getValue()));
    }
}
```

I have disabled Spring Security by adding `.anyRequsts().permitAll()` to my `SecurityConfig`

When I run the application, and navigate to `/admin` in Chrome, I get the following error displayed where the page is meant to be.:

```
Webpack Error

ERROR in ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@vaadin/vaadin-button/src/vaadin-button.js' in 'C:\Users\cameron\IdeaProjects\biometric-access\target\frontend'
 @ ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports.js 11:0-52
```

This is repeated a few times for various packages. I also get a similar error in the Spring console output. It also gives a message telling me to delete `node_modules`, and run `npm install`, which I have tried.

The Vaadin docs mention nothing about this issue, and the reccomended steps do not work.

Infuriatingly, It worked as normal previously, and I don't know what change made it stop working. Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT

After some searching, I realised it was probably an npm issue rather than a vaadin issue. The npm "common issues" page recommends running `npm clean` followed by `npm install` to solve this error. This solved my problem.

Comment: Have you run the `prepare-frontend` target beforehand? https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/production/tutorial-production-mode-basic.html

Comment: Tried that, with no luck, found a solution that worked for me so will post that

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after updating from Vaadin 14.0.0 to 14.0.2 .
Deleting the `node_modules` folder and running `prepare-frontend` goal is not enough.

Delete following files and folders before packaging your project:

- node_modules
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- webpack.config.js
- webpack.generated.js

Would be nice to have something like a "clean" goal to do this automatically after updating the vaadin version in the pom.xml

Comment: Yeah, in the end `npm clean` did it for me. Would be nice if that was included in the in the maven clean goal.

Comment: @cameron1024 If you found a different or better way to solve your problem, please add it as your own answer.